# C# WPF multiple windows

Tags: c#, wpf

probably a beginner question,

I develop in c # wpf a graphical application with different windows, if I now open a new window with button and there, for example, capture a customer, then how can the other window still remain interactible with the open table?

or how can I run a function in another window that is supposed to update a DataGrid of another window (other .xaml file)?

Comment: You might want to take a closer look at the MVC- or MVVM-pattern.

Comment: Wdym capture a customer?

Answer (score 0):

Because neither window should actually control the access or view of the underlying data, they both interact with it via a intermediary class/object.

For WPF this pattern is commonly MVVM: Model, View, ViewModel.  Your WPF Windows/Forms are the Views, and the data interaction will be in the ViewModel and Model.

I've not had to learn this in a while, but [LearnMVVM](http://www.learnmvvm.com/) looks to be reasonable starting point.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you Implement a `ViewModel` (if youre lazy there is [MVVM Lite](http://www.mvvmlight.net/)) with public or internal access mods. Then call the specified method to update the `ViewModel`.
You can pass a reference from your 2nd Window to your MainWindow by passing it though the constructor if you, for some reason, cant use static constructs.

Comment: okay thanks first, was the entire WPF project free or can you just pull it over?

Comment: @PatrickKranig MVVM Lite is open source, They are aiming to encourage programmers new to WPF to use ViewModels. Normally they are very complicated, but with MVVM Lite ViewModels are easy to manage. [Here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvvmLight) is the link to their NuGet package

Comment: @PatrickKranig No, it doesnt change anything for you, you could even use standard ViewModels instead of MVVM Lite assisted ViewModels even while its installed. All of it is completely optional. But the code with which you feed your GUI needs to be remastered completely

Answer (score 0):

What are you looking for is MVVM-Design Pattern (or MVC):

Model − It simply holds the data and has nothing to do with any of the business logic.

ViewModel − It acts as the link/connection between the Model and View and makes stuff look pretty.

View − It simply holds the formatted data and essentially delegates everything to the Model.

[Wikipedia: MVVM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel)

[Tutorialpoint: MVVM-tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvvm/index.htm)